# Gradient of a matrix polynomial

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Given the vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^h$ and the matrix $V  \in \mathbb{R}^{h \times h}$, let $o : \mathbb{R}^{h \times h} \to \mathbb{R}^h$ be defined by

$$ o (U) : = V  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} U^i b $$

Compute the gradient $\nabla_U o$.

---

I found

$$ \nabla_U o (U)  = \left[   \sum_{i=0} ^{n-1}\sum_{j=0} ^{n-1}\left[  U^jb U^{n-1-j} b \right] \right]$$

but a friend told me that's wrong and I can't where. Can someone please help me? Is this really wrong?

Comment: What is V? And C? Perhaps you mean $b\in\mathbb R^h\,$? And are $b,V,C$ constant?

Comment: $o$ is not a wonderful name for a function

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I agree, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\o{{\tt1}} \def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=\o}^{n-1}}
\def\Sj{\sum_{j=\o}^k}
\def\A{A_{pq}}
\def\E{E_{pq}}
$Let me introduce some nicer variable names
$$\eqalign{
A &= U \\
f &= o(A) \;=\; Vb \;+\; V\;{\Sk A^kb} \\
}$$
Let's assume that you reached the following point in your derivation

$\big(\bf NB\!:\:$ There was a mistake on the limits of your $j$-summation.$\,\big)$
$$\eqalign{
df &= V\LR{\Sk\Sj A^{k-j}\:\c{dA}\;A^{j-\o}b} \in\bbR{h} \\
}$$
The issue is finding the correct way to rearrange this differential expression into a proper gradient.

One way to do that is to use the component-wise$\;$self-gradient
of the $A$ matrix
$$\grad{A}{\A} = \E \:\in\:\bbR{h\times h} $$
where $\E$ is the so-called *single-entry matrix* whose $(p,q)$ component is equal to one and all other components are equal to zero.

This immediately yields the component-wise gradients of the function
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{\A} &= V\LR{\Sk\Sj A^{k-j}\:\c{\E}\;A^{j-\o}b} \in\bbR{h} \\
}$$
But the full vector-by-matrix gradient is a third-order tensor.
In order to calculate that, we need to introduce two special products.

$\tt1\big)\:$The Frobenius product $(:)$ is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij}Y_{ij} \;=\; \trace{X^TY} \\
X:X &= \|X\|^2_F \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \} \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

$\tt2\big)\:$The Dyadic product $(\star)$ concatenates its arguments
to create a higher-order tensor, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
\def\G{{\large\Omega}}
\G &= X\star Y \qiq \G_{ijkl} = X_{ij}Y_{kl} \\\\
}$$
These products can be used to rearrange the differential expression into the required form
$$\eqalign{
df &= V\LR{\Sk\Sj A^{k-j}\star\LR{A^{j-\o}b}} : \c{dA} \\
\grad{f}{A}
  &= V\LR{\Sk\Sj A^{k-j}\star\LR{A^{j-\o}b}} \in\bbR{h\times h\times h} \\
}$$

Yet another way to approach the problem is to
[vectorize the matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) on the RHS of the differential expression
$\Big(da={\rm vec}(dA)\Big)$ and calculate the Jacobian
$\,\large\LR{\grad{f}{a}}$